# mail validation suggestions

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using some thing like signup page, after the user finishes his registeration form an email is send to him including a link which when pressed redirect him to page which confirm his registration , so any suggestions how to do that with google app engine (even the concept)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- create GUID - java.util.UUID.
- put this GUID into database table along with timestamp
- generate the confirmation link with GUID as a parameter and email it to the user
- once link is hit by the user, check that passed GUID exist in DB (and valid, not expired), complete registration and delete GUID record from database